# Total Curvature for a curve in a metric space

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, curves, curvature, metric-geometry

Is there a theorem involving total curvature and some notion of index number for a curve in a metric space, as there is for planar curves? (i.e. total curvature is an integer multiple of $2\pi$.)

I'm guessing "no", at least not with this exact definitions, since they fall apart even in $\mathbb{R}^3$. However, I was wondering if there are any similar theorems/notions for a general metric space.

Edit: I'm thinking of using this as the curvature: (from wikipedia)

Given two points $P$ and $Q$ on $C$, let $s(P, Q)$ be the arc length of the portion of the curve between $P$ and $Q$ and let $d(P, Q)$ denote the length of the line segment from $P$ to $Q$. The curvature of $C$ at $P$ is given by the limit
$$
\kappa(P)=\lim _{Q \rightarrow P} \sqrt{\frac{24(s(P, Q)-d(P, Q))}{s(P, Q)^{3}}}
$$

Comment: Your total curvature integral in the plane is using *signed* curvature. In higher dimensions, there's no such sign. You might look at Fenchel's Theorem, however. In a general metric space (where we have no notion of differentiability), how are you thinking of curvature?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your response! There's a notion of curvature for curves in metric spaces in general, not using differentiability but only the metric:


(from wikipedia)


Given two points $P$ and $Q$ on $C$, let $s(P, Q)$ be the arc length of the portion of the curve between $P$ and $Q$ and let $d(P, Q)$ denote the length of the line segment from $P$ to $Q$. The curvature of $C$ at $P$ is given by the limit
$$
\kappa(P)=\lim _{Q \rightarrow P} \sqrt{\frac{24(s(P, Q)-d(P, Q))}{s(P, Q)^{3}}}
$$

It is equal to the curvature defined for curves in $R^n$

Comment: I know about curvature of the space itself, not of curves in the metric space. Please explain if you know a notion of the latter.

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited my comment.

Comment: Ah, yes, I’ve seen that. But how would you make sense of integrating, i.e., “total” curvature?

Comment: @TedShifrin That's a good point. I was thinking by integrating the pushback of the curvature, as a function, via the curve. i.e. if the curve is $c: [0,1] \to X$, $X$ being the metric space, then we can define the curvature to be:
$\int_0^1{\kappa(c(t))}dt$
but now that I'm articulating it, I'm not sure if it's well-defined.

Comment: Certainly it is not. :( This comes back to the important point that it is the integral of differential forms, and not that of functions, that is well-defined.

Comment: @TedShifrin could you please explain this a bit more? I'm familiar with how the integral of differential forms are well-defined, but I don't see the connection to this.

Comment: You have a function here, obviously. Look at what happens when you reparametrize. The chain rule messes up your integral.

Comment: @TedShifrin $\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$We don’t have a definition of differentiability on a metric space? I thought that the following definition held for any metric space: “If $X,Y$ are two metric spaces, $f:X\to Y$, $\d f:X\to Y$ is a linear map, and $p_0\in X$, define $\psi:X\to Y$ by: $$\psi(p-p_0)=f(p)-f(p_0)-\d f(p-p_0)$$If $\psi(p-p_0)$ is continuous in some neighbourhood of $p_0$ (by the metric topology) and if $\|\psi(p-p_0)\|\in o\|p-p_0\|$ as $p\to p_0$, then $f$ is said to the differentiable at $p_0$ and the linear map $\d f$ is called the differential of $f$ at $p_0$.”

Comment: @TedShifrin I agree that reparametrization changes the integral, but I don't see how the chain rule comes into play?
Also, if we fix the parametrization, for example w.t.t. arc length, then it's well-defined, right?

Comment: The same way it does any time you change variables in an integral. That’s precisely why it’s the integrals of differential forms that are well-defined.

Comment: @TedShifrin oh I see, thanks. The reason that I'm interested in total curvature right now is that I'm trying to find a way to somehow describe "a half turn" in a metric space. I thought if there was a notion of total curvature there, then I could define the half turn to have half of total curvature of a closed curve. But with the not-well-defined-ness and also lack of "sign" for the curvature, I'm starting to think that perhaps I should find another way. Do you have an idea of how it might be possible?

Comment: @TedShifrin Also, this definition not being well-defined isn't unique to this situation, is it? the same problem must hold for a planar curve also.

Comment: No, in the Euclidean case we are integrating with respect to arclength, so no interesting reparametrization is possible. Moreover, it really is the integral of a 1-form. It seems to me the notion of half-turn requires some sort of angle measure or perhaps at least an affine structure. I don’t know.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks! Then can't we do the same thing here, i.e. parametrize w.r.t to arc length and then integrate along that?

Comment: Perhaps so. I guess rectifiability works in any (complete?) metric space.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see. This was a very helpful discussion, thank you very much!